# How to open a Pdf file with touching on that and open with my application

Tags: android

I am developing an application to read Pdf files. So I want to know how to can I get file path when I touch that file in android file explorer (like Es explorer) with selecting my app from "select list" and open it. I attached a select menu image at below.
Nevertheless, How to can I do that?

[image]

Comment: You should add an intent filter in you Manifest.
Maybe [this](https://github.com/ieee8023/PDFViewer/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) can help you :

Comment: The user can already select your app? If so use getIntent() in the used activity.

Comment: Dear AceStan thanks for your attention. I added that but I want to know, how to can I handle that in Activity

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters).

So short answer is that in your `onCreate` method you get the intent and check to see if the file type is a PDF and do what your app does to read that PDF.